# Range in benchmarking

Tags: benchmarking, benchmark

What if we don't provide range inside benchmark and provide 10 in **steps** while running benchmark?
Is there any default range provided by framework or is there anything else will happen in this case?

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at the implementation here:

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/utils/frame/benchmarking-cli/src/pallet/command.rs

```rust
let mut all_components = Vec::new();
for (idx, (name, low, high)) in components.iter().enumerate() {
    let lowest = self.lowest_range_values.get(idx).cloned().unwrap_or(*low);
    let highest = self.highest_range_values.get(idx).cloned().unwrap_or(*high);

    let diff = highest - lowest;

    // Create up to `STEPS` steps for that component between high and low.
    let step_size = (diff / self.steps).max(1);
    let num_of_steps = diff / step_size + 1;
    for s in 0..num_of_steps {
        // This is the value we will be testing for component `name`
        let component_value = lowest + step_size * s;

        // Select the max value for all the other components.
        let c: Vec<(BenchmarkParameter, u32)> = components
            .iter()
            .enumerate()
            .map(|(idx, (n, _, h))| {
                if n == name {
                    (*n, component_value)
                } else {
                    (*n, *self.highest_range_values.get(idx).unwrap_or(h))
                }
            })
            .collect();
        all_components.push(c);
    }
}
all_components
```

So in the case you don't have a range, we only have 1 step for "steps", and will use all the repeats.